# Kivy/MySQL, checking if a username and password exists in the database not working even if it exists

Tags: python, mysql, user-interface, authentication, kivy

I'm really new to Kivy and I might've made mistakes here, so any sort of help would be highly appreciated. I am trying to make a simple login system in Kivy and I have run into this problem. I am trying to print "success" if the values exist in the database but it does not print it even though it exists in the database.

**Python:**

```
import kivy
import mysql.connector
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import mysql.connector

Builder.load_file("my.kv")

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    db="kivydatabase",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    user="root",
    password="[password]"
)

cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)

class registerScreen(Screen):

    usernameInput = ObjectProperty(None)
    emailInput = ObjectProperty(None)
    passwordInput = ObjectProperty(None)

    def addInfoToDB(self):
        query = "INSERT INTO registeredusers (Username, Email, Password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
        values = (self.usernameInput.text, self.emailInput.text, self.passwordInput.text)
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        db.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")

class loginScreen(Screen):

    usernameInputLogin = ObjectProperty(None)
    passwordInputLogin = ObjectProperty(None)

    def checkIfDetailsExist(self):
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM registeredusers")
        fetchInfo = cursor.fetchone()

        if self.usernameInputLogin.text in fetchInfo and self.passwordInputLogin.text in fetchInfo:
            print("success")
        else:
            print("fail")



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(loginScreen(name='login'))
        sm.add_widget(registerScreen(name='register'))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv:**

```
<registerScreen>

    usernameInput: usernameInput
    emailInput: emailInput
    passwordInput: passwordInput
    
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label: 
                text: "Username: "

            TextInput: 
                multiline: False
                id: usernameInput
            
            Label: 
                text: "Email: "
            
            TextInput: 
                multiline: False
                id: emailInput

            Label: 
                text: "Password: "

            TextInput: 
                multiline: False
                id: passwordInput

        Button: 
            on_press: root.addInfoToDB()
            text: "Submit"
            size_hint: (.5, .4)
            
        Button: 
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'login'
            text: "Login"
            size_hint: (.5, .4)

<loginScreen>

    usernameInputLogin: usernameInputLogin
    passwordInputLogin: passwordInputLogin

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label: 
                text: "Username: "

            TextInput: 
                multiline: False
                id: usernameInputLogin

            Label: 
                text: "Password: "

            TextInput: 
                multiline: False
                id: passwordInputLogin
            
        Button: 
            on_press: root.checkIfDetailsExist()
            text: "Submit"
            size_hint: (.5, .4)
        
        Button: 
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'register'
            text: "Register"
            size_hint: (.5, .4)
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the kivy script. Try debugging your logic. Use print statements in between your ```checkIfDetailExist``` to ensure that everything is valid. This is also a good time to implement unittests to verify your functions. Also, try putting your boolean checks in parenthesis to ensure that the proper logic is being carried out.

Comment: Okay, also, shouldn't I be using fetchall() since we're checking if the input value exists in the somewhere in the database. even though it does not work, im just curious.

Comment: Unittest says its fine